# Getting the format of a base64 encoded string using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

I have searched in a lot of different places but could not find the answer to this.

It seems like the suggested way of guessing the extension of base64 encoded string (The string does not have an extension in it and its a valid image) is to use PIL package. This is what I am currently doing.

But when I attempt to open the image I get the error `cannot identify image file`.

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong ?

```
#img_content is base64 encoded string     
decodedbytes = base64.decodebytes(str.encode(image_content))
image_stream = StringIO(str(decodedbytes))
image = Image.open(image_stream) #<-----ERROR
filetype = image.format
```

Comment: Try to use `BytesIO` directly? Images shouldn't be a string.

Comment: what do u mean ? can you explain where to use BytesIO ?

Comment: I mean maybe you should treat it as bytes. For example, use `BytesIO(decodedbytes)` instead of `StringIO(str(decodedbytes))`.

Comment: yup that did the trick

Comment: glad to help that :)